# How to convert API (route) to CLI on expressjs

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes, command-line-interface

For example:
I have a route like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/source1/test
```

now I want to run it by:

```
node index.js --first=source1 --second=test
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do by using module:

[command-line-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args)

```
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const optionDefinitions = [
  {name: 'route', alias: 'r', type: String}
];
const option = commandLineArgs(optionDefinitions);
```

Then we can use the switch case to do the function we want. However, we have to convert all API to normal function with its parameter.